# How to check a category checkbox using JavaScript

Tags: categories, jquery, javascript, admin

I'm making this link, that sends an extra parameter to the admin-panel, as such:

```
/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=CPT&msscategory=40
```

Then I enqueue some javascript on that given page as such (added as an action to `admin_footer`):

```
$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( in_array( $screen->id, array( 'CPT' ) ) && $screen->action == 'add' ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'mark-default-category', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

And then I would like to check the category-checkbox that has `id=39`. But I can't get my head around the HTML. It looks like this:

```
<li id='category-39'>
  <label class="selectit">
    <input value="39" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" 
           id="in-category-39" /> 
    Page 1 (depth 0)
  </label>
  <ul class='children'>
    <li id='category-40' class="popular-category">
      <label class="selectit">
        <input value="40" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" 
               id="in-category-40" /> 
        Page 2 (depth 1)
      </label>  
      <ul class='children'>
        <li id='category-41'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="41" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]"
                   id="in-category-41" /> 
            Page 3 (depth 2)
          </label>
        </li>
        <li id='category-42'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="42" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]"
                   id="in-category-42" /> 
            Page 3 (depth 2)
          </label>
        </li>
        <li id='category-43'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="43" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" 
                   id="in-category-43" /> 
            Page 4 (depth 2)
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

As can be seen, then the `input`-checkbox has no attribute (attr) or property (prop) called `checked`. This is a label before it's clicked:

```
 <label class="selectit">
   <input value="43" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" 
          id="in-category-43" /> 
   Page 4 (depth 2)
 </label>
```

And this is one *after* it has been clicked:

```
 <label class="selectit">
   <input value="43" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" 
          id="in-category-43">
     ::before
   </input> 
   Page 4 (depth 2)
 </label>
```

So all that happens is that the `input`-field no longer self-closes, - but that `::before` is added.

Now, - how do I do that with jQuery?

This is the closest I've gotten.

```
var finding_the_checkbox = jQuery('#category' + just_the_category_ID ).find("label");
findind_the_checkbox.click()
```

... While formulating this, then I found the solution. I'll post that below (since I couldn't find an answer anywhere else. The internet needs this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery( '#in-category-43' ).prop('checked', true);
});
```